# Adding / Replacing Items in a Listbox in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have been around the web with no success, but could really use the help.
I have an unbound Listbox that is set to "Value List".  What I am trying to accomplish is to add items to the listbox. I have no issues with adding the items in multiple columns, but...

Once I get a full list, around 10 items, I want to be able to go back to the top of the list and replace the items that were added with new items....without losing the old items...essentially replacing them one at a time.

So:  What I have is....(which works fine.  A new item is added every so many minutes.)

```
Me.MyListBox.AddItem MyCol1 & ";" MyCol2
```

Now, after the list get to around 10 items, I want to go to the (choose any number), 3rd item in the list and replace it.  I thought it would look like this...(but it is not working)

```
Me.MyListBox.AddItem(MyCol1 & ";" MyCol2, [2])
```

I'm just needing a little assistance understanding the syntax of this line.
A little direction in this would be so very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out.  There may be better answers than this, but this worked for me.

The syntax is:

```
Me.MyListBox.AddItem Item:=MyCol1 & ";" MyCol2, Index:=x
```

***x*** being whatever position you want to add your item to the listbox.  Just remember that **0** is the first row of the listbox.

Comment: You can select this as the answer to your own question with the green checkmark to the left. It will close out the question so people know it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As ListIndex starting from 0, to replace liste item #3, we can do this:

```
  dim iIndextItem = 3
  iIndextItem = 3 - 1
  
  Me.MyListBox.RemoveItem iIndextItem 
  Me.MyListBox.AddItem "new value 3", iIndextItem
```

This replacement method will keep the list at the same length ( Me.MyListBox.ListCount).